# Return inserted Id after sqlite3_finalize

Tags: iphone, ios4, sqlite

Here is the code I am using to insert a record into the table... all I need is this function to capture and return back the inserted id of the record... is this possible? This code is working fine and returns YES for successful insert and NO for failures... but now im trying to return an integer insert id... but cant seem to figure out a way...

```
-(BOOL)insertEvent:(Event *)objEvent { Utils *objUtils = [[Utils alloc] init];

sqlite3_stmt *insertStmt = nil;
sqlite3 *aDatabase = nil;

int ret = sqlite3_enable_shared_cache(1);

if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &aDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    if(insertStmt == nil)
    {           
        NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO tblEvent ('eventstartdate','eventdescription') VALUES ('%@','%@')",objEvent.eventstartdate, objEvent.eventdescription];
        const char *sql = [aString UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(aDatabase, sql, -1, &insertStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating insertTip add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(aDatabase));
            return NO;
        }
        [objUtils release];
    }

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(insertStmt)) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting into TipsTracker. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(aDatabase));
        return NO;
    }
    sqlite3_reset(insertStmt);

    if (insertStmt)
    {
        sqlite3_finalize(insertStmt);
        insertStmt = nil;
    }
}
sqlite3_close(aDatabase);
aDatabase = nil;
return YES;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this function `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);`

Comment: you need to change "database" with your database object "aDatabase" are you doing that?

Comment: nevermind... I was printing it in NSLog(@"%@",...) but had to do NSLog(@"%lld",..) ... thanks to xcode4 for good recommendation :)

Comment: do u know how to convert long long int to integer?

Comment: Actually you should not convert long long int to integer because LLD has a bigger range and if the value is bigger then integer range it will not get fit into it.. hope you are getting it.